# How to get all services autostarting on windows using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I need to list all services with a special name and a index and their autostart status. My thoughts were to use a batch and something like sc query but this doesn't give me the required information.

This is what I tried

```
sc query service
sc query service2
sc query service3
pause
```

Which command is suitable to list the start setting for a service?

Comment: You can use the WMI Command utility, e.g. `WMIC Service Where "Name='service2'" Get Name, StartMode`.

Comment: Maybe you could use `sc qc service` (`qc`=query configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use powershell, as `sc query` does not display startup type by default:

To see startup type by Display name, open `cmd.exe` and type (or paste):

```
powershell "Get-Service | select -property displayname,starttype"
```

or by actaul service name:

```
powershell "Get-Service | select -property name,starttype"
```

or you can create a powershell script by creating a file and give it a `.ps1` extension and adding:

```
Get-Service | select -property name,starttype
```

or if you really want to use batch file, simply create a batch file with `.cmd` or `.bat` extension and add:

```
powershell "Get-Service | select -property name,starttype"
```

But, if you really are determined to use batch, you can run this which runs 2 for loops, one to get all the services, second will get the startup type of each. the `set`'s are simply there to cleanup some unwanted items.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%i in ('sc query ^|findstr "SERVICE_NAME"') do (
   set serv=%%j
   set serv=!serv: =!
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('sc qc !serv! ^| findstr "START_TYPE"') do set type=%%b
    set type=!type: =!
    set type=!type:1=!
    set type=!type:2=!
    set type=!type:3=!
    echo !serv! : !type!
)
```